# Array only fills on first iteration of loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a results table with multiple results for multiple samples, and a sample list array containing each unique sample reference value in the results table.

I am trying to loop through the sample list to:

- Filter the results table for each sample.
- Fill an array with the filtered values
- Create a new sheet for each sample
- Output the array to the new sheet

The code works for the first iteration of the loop however, on each subsequent run through, the array only contains a single row, and only the table header values are output to the created sheets.

```vb
'define excel variables
Dim resultTable As ListObject
Dim resultsArr() As Variant
Dim fr As Worksheet
Dim samplelist() As Variant
Dim sheetname As String

'Set excel variables
Set fr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formatted Results")

'Formatted_Results is named table in sheet fr
Set resultTable = fr.ListObjects("Formatted_Results")

'This selects unique values from the Original Sample column
' (it is set as a named range in sheet fr)
samplelist = WorksheetFunction.Unique(Range("ORIGINAL_SAMPLE")) 

'Start loop for each unique sample number -
For Each sampleNo In samplelist
    resultTable.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sampleNo 
    'autofilter on sampleNo
    resultsArr = resultTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    sheetname = "Sample " & sampleNo
    Sheets.Add.Name = sheetname
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname)
        .Range("A6").Resize(UBound(resultsArr, 1), UBound(resultsArr, 2)).Value = resultsArr
    End With
Next sampleNo
```

Comment: Have you checked (using the debugger) that `sampleNo` always contains something that is part of your table? Hold you code after setting the filter and check in Excel if the table is filtered as expected.

Comment: can you check the values of  resultsArr = resultTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) on each interation. i believe that it does not contain all the rows

Comment: @FunThomas  I checked and sampleNo always contains a value from the table. The autofilter step is also working as I can view the filtering of the table change as expected when running through the code step by step.

Comment: @Luis Curado It does seem to be the  resultsArr = resultTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) statement that is not  working after the first iteration. In each subsequent iteration the array only contains the column headers from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access a filtered list via SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), the result is a non-contiguous range. Copying data from such a range copies only the values from the first Subrange.

I am not aware that there is a build-in way to copy the data of all subranges at once. You will need to loop over the subranges manually. You can access the subranges with the `Areas`-property of a range. Areas works for every range, so if the range *is* contiguous, Areas(1) accesses the whole range.

```
Dim r as Range, a as Range, row as Long
Set r = resultTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
row = 1
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname)
For Each a In r.Areas
    .Cells(row, 6).Resize(a.Rows.Count, a.Columns.Count) = a.Value2
    row = row + a.Rows.Count
Next
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas! I think understand what the problem was now. I was confused as to why the first iteration worked but it makes sense if it only returns the first subrange. The first sample's results would be in the same subrange as the headers as they are contiguous. I have incorporated your suggested  code and it is now working as intended.  Thank you again!